# Vector of closures in Rust

Tags: rust, closures

I'm using a XLFormula_engine to compute a very large number of variable in a database  using formulas also stored in database too.

This is a basic example with the library:

```
extern crate xlformula_engine;
use xlformula_engine::calculate;
use xlformula_engine::parse_formula;
use xlformula_engine::types;
use xlformula_engine::NoCustomFunction;

let data_function = |s: String| match s.as_str() {
    "A" => types::Value::Number(10.12),
    "B" => types::Value::Number(123.0),
    _ => types::Value::Error(types::Error::Value),
    };

let formula = parse_formula::parse_string_to_formula(&"=IF(A>0,B/A,0)", None::<NoCustomFunction>);

let result = calculate::calculate_formula(formula, Some(&data_function));
```

How can I get into a result vector this getting the formulas, "A" & "B" variables as vectors ?

Now I think I should remove the Rust language terms and rephrase the question:

In a database I have a very large number of compound formulas such as

```
var | formula 
k | a/b
j | if(a>0,a/b,0)
x | sum(r)
```

in another table I have the values of variables in formulae such as

```
var | value
a | 20.9
b | 55.8
r | 3.8
```

It's possible to use the library mentioned or an equivalent one to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused how the vector of closures is supposed to fit into this code. A vector of A & B to evaluate with? A vector of formulas to evaluate? A vector of variables with values (i.e. A, B, C, D...)? I'm assuming the first one, which is possible via a vector of closures, but just double checking.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, was not clear...sorry

Comment: Is there any significance to the `var` column for the formulae? For example, can the result of one formula appear in another formula? Also, do you only have one set of variables?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. A value computed should be used or reused multiple time. AFAIK this library solve the dependency with AST but I've to inject it to have the result. The vars a, b and r are basic value, while k, j, x always variable coming from formulas, and another kind is constant, but just as the first set.

Answer (score 0):

Were you perhaps looking for something like

```
let aa = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
let bb = [42.0, 4.2, 84.0];

let formula =
    parse_formula::parse_string_to_formula(&"=IF(A>0,B/A,0)", None::<NoCustomFunction>);
let results = Iterator::zip(aa.iter(), bb.iter())
    .map(|(&a, &b)| {
        calculate::calculate_formula(
            formula.clone(),
            Some(&|s: String| match s.as_str() {
                "A" => types::Value::Number(a),
                "B" => types::Value::Number(b),
                _ => types::Value::Error(types::Error::Value),
            }),
        )
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
// results is [Number(0.0), Number(4.2), Number(42.0)]
```

The `aa`, `bb`, and `results` are some examples I came up based on my interpretation of the last sentence in your question. If that's not it: For SO questions, it's often helpful to make this kind of short example input and output data.

---

Well, second guess.

```rust
use xlformula_engine::{
    calculate::calculate_formula,
    parse_formula::{self, parse_string_to_formula},
    types::Value,
    NoCustomFunction,
};

let vals = [("a", 20.9), ("b", 55.8), ("r", 3.8)];
let forms = [
    ("k", "=a/b"),
    ("j", "=IF(a>0,a/b,0)"),
    ("x", "=SUM(r)"),
    ("y", "=x + k + a"),
    ("u", "=v"),
    ("v", "=u"),
];

let mut results = HashMap::new();
for (name, value) in vals.iter() {
    if results.insert(*name, Value::Number(*value)).is_some() {
        return Err("Duplicate value".into());
    }
}
let forms = HashMap::from(forms); // TODO: dupe key check?
let results = RefCell::new(results); // calculate_formula wants an Fn, meaning we have to hide the fact we mutate some data. :(

fn invalid() -> Value {
    Value::Error(xlformula_engine::types::Error::Reference)
}
fn calc<'vars>(
    var: &str,
    forms: &HashMap<&'vars str, &str>,
    results: &RefCell<HashMap<&'vars str, Value>>,
) -> Value {
    if let Some(res) = results.borrow().get(var) {
        return res.clone();
    }
    let Some((var, formula)) = forms.get_key_value(var) else { return invalid() }; // replace var here because the keys of forms have a longer lifetime
    results.borrow_mut().insert(var, invalid()); // Hedge against infinite recursion due to mutually recursive formulas
    let res = calculate_formula(
        parse_string_to_formula(formula, None::<NoCustomFunction>),
        Some(&|s: String| {
            // stacker magic prevents stack overflows
            stacker::maybe_grow(32 * 1024, 1024 * 1024, || calc(&s, forms, results))
        }),
    );
    assert!(results.borrow_mut().insert(var, res.clone()).is_some());
    res
}
stacker::maybe_grow(32 * 1024, 1024 * 1024, || {
    forms.keys().for_each(|var| {
        calc(var, &forms, &results);
    })
});

println!("{results:#?}");
```

Comment: Nice try thanks, but the variable and the assignment depend on a DB table, please see the rephrase above

Comment: Your description still doesn't make the problem very clear..

Comment: `Iterator::zip()` -> `std::iter::zip()`.

Comment: Because I could have gotten away with `std::iter::zip(&aa, &bb)`? Mmmh. Nah.